# maximize image and keep the best quality

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap, image-resizing, android-bitmap

On android, is their any way to maximize a bitmap (to show it at full screen) and keep at the same time the best quality as possible ? actually i do like this:

```
aMatrix.postScale(ARatio, ARatio);  
createBitmap(aBitmap{src}, round(aSrcRect.Left){X}, round(aSrcRect.top){Y}, round(aSrcRect.width){Width}, round(aSrcRect.height){height}, aMatrix{m}, True{filter});
```

but the quality of the resized bitmap is very slow :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to increase the image quality of a bitmap image beyond what you already have. What you're looking for is a scalable vector graphic or `.svg`, you can find more information on using them in Android here:

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html